# Query to fetch custom taxonomy along with post title

Tags: posts, custom-taxonomy, query, mysql

I have more than 20000 posts and want to filter post based on taxonomy and name  which should display the
post title ,taxonomy, name,id using MYSQL query.

Comment: Is there a reason you  want to use a raw SQL query rather than the APIs such as `WP_Query` or a REST API request? A raw SQL query skips all filters, avoids object ad query caches, and will mean none of the supporting data is pre-fetched, there will be lots of tiny follow up queries for things like post meta or permalinks

Comment: I agreed Tom. However I  want to perform data analysis from database for different posts so if any changes is required i can validate the same and remediate accordingly and if anyone needed to perform any data cleaning they can refer the same.this is going to list all the key field ie custom taxonomy,post title .

Answer (score 0):

If we want to display taxonomy name along with post title in backend MYSQL query you can use this query :-

```
SELECT   p.ID,taxonomy,post_title,post_status,name
FROM    wp_posts p, wp_term_relationships rel, wp_terms t, wp_term_taxonomy 
te
where  
   p.ID = rel.object_id
  AND t.term_id=te.term_id
  AND t.term_id=rel.term_taxonomy_id
  AND taxonomy in ('taxonomy')
  AND Post_type='post'
  and name='name of taxonomy'
```